# Android findViewById() return null only on Oreo

Tags: android

I'm trying to integrate [this code](https://mobikul.com/expandable-floating-action-button-fab-menu/) in my app with only 2 FloatingActionButton not 3 like the example. But I get the error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.setLayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams)' on a null object reference
```

The problem is that this error only occurs on Android Oreo and only at two lines of "findViewById()" and the third "findViewById()" before is all fine.

here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

FloatingActionButton fabFCB, fabManual;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

...................
...................

    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fabBtn); // this line works fine
    fabFCB = findViewById(R.id.fabBtn1);  //this line return null and the next one
    fabManual = findViewById(R.id.fabBtn2);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
         RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
         RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END);
    params.bottomMargin = pxfromDp(20.0f);
    params.setMarginEnd(pxfromDp(20.0f));
    fab.setLayoutParams(params);
    fabFCB.setLayoutParams(params); // this line where the error occurs
    fabManual.setLayoutParams(params);

...................
...................


     }
}
```

I checked the ID names and changed it many times but no luck.
I even tried to find view by id through LayoutInflater but also no luck

```
LayoutInflater inflator = this.getLayoutInflater();
    View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.activity_main,null);
    fabFCB = v.findViewById(R.id.fabBtn1);
    fabManual = v.findViewById(R.id.fabBtn2);
```

here is the id part of the layout

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fabBtn2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
            android:background="@color/indigo"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/indigo"
            android:src="@drawable/baseline_add_white_24"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/indigo"
            app:elevation="6dp"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
            app:targetApi="o" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fabBtn1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
            android:background="@color/indigo"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/indigo"
            android:src="@drawable/baseline_add_white_24"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/indigo"
            app:elevation="6dp"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
            app:targetApi="o" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fabBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
            android:background="@color/indigo"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/indigo"
            android:src="@drawable/baseline_add_white_24"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/indigo"
            app:elevation="6dp"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
            app:targetApi="o" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

I'm using Android Studio 3.3 and my compileSdkVersion is 28

Comment: Silly question, but are you sure you do not maybe have another layout file defined somewhere for Oreo? I've made this mistake before because I forgot to add an item to my other layout file - in my case it was landscape v portrait layout files.

Comment: I have just a recommendation for you. Why doing the fab button for yourself when you have so many stable libraries for this? Here are two of them, check them out: https://github.com/leinardi/FloatingActionButtonSpeedDial , https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton

Comment: Most probably you are doing wrong Import.. So remove your Import for FAB and re import and select support lib import

Comment: Can you take screenshot of your project structure and post here. Do expand layout folder.

Comment: @android, Thank you for your suggestion, sure I will reconsider if I couldn't fix this.

Comment: @IntsabHaider, checked it and still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys, @Zee and @Chandrakant Dvivedi. there was a layout file for V26 which I don't know anything about and I did not even creat. that was the root of the problem. I deleted it and everything is working like charm.